# VisualStudio error: An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Tags: c#, mysql

When trying to insert the following information into my database I get "An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

My code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace wsiz
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\rf\Documents\wsiz.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30");
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Table (imie,nazwisko,miasto) VALUES ('" + textBox1.Text + "','" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox3.Text +"');";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();

            MessageBox.Show("record inserted successfully");

        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Full Exception details

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException occurred
  Class=15
  ErrorCode=-2146232060
  HResult=-2146232060
  LineNumber=1
  Message=Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'Table'.
  Number=156
  Procedure=""
  Server=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB
  Source=.Net SqlClient Data Provider
  State=1
  StackTrace:
       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
       w System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteNonQueryTds(String methodName, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
       w System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
       w wsiz.Form1.button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) w c:\users\rf\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\wsiz\wsiz\Form1.cs:wiersz 28
  InnerException:
```

Comment: Exceptions have details and messages. Could you share? I would guess at least one of your text box values do not have what you think they have.

Comment: Post the full exception, including stacktrace and inner exception (if any). Also, provide the table structure of the table you are attempting to insert into. Right now, there is insufficient information to solve your problem.

Comment: Table
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Table] (
    [Id]       INT          NOT NULL,
    [imie]     VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [nazwisko] VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [miasto]   VARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);

Comment: @Defus don't link to a third party site with information about your error, and don't just provide it in the comments, just edit it into your question... Also, what data are you entering into the textboxes? Are you sure the value you are trying to insert into the integer column is an actual integer?

Comment: Edited questions. I am not entering anything into ID (int)

Comment: Is your table really named "Table"? If so wrap it so it is not a keyword: `[Table]`

Comment: @Defus, read about how to use `SqlParameter`. If you concatenate strings into a query, especially if you take the values straight out of a text box without any validation, someone can do great harm to your database - and very easily with sql injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your immediate error is because you are using the keyword `Table`. Instead use `[Table]`.

```
"INSERT INTO [Table] (imie,nazwisko,miasto) VALUES ..."
```

After that, you should start looking into query parameterization in order to prevent sql injection and to help with debugging and extendability.